# Get the name in a WordPress get_object_taxonomies query, not the slug

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a taxonomy query which returns the slugs of the taxonomy. I would like to know how I can get the name instead.

Here is the query:

```
<?php  
$tax_query = array();

foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( 'exam' ) as $tax ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ $tax ] ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'terms' => wp_unslash( ( array ) $_POST[ $tax ] ),
            'field' => 'slug',          
        );
    }
}

$args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args['paged'] = $paged;  
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($the_query);

?>

<?php
foreach ($tax_query as $key => $value) {
        $result = $value;
        $exam_board = $value["terms"][0];
        var_dump($result);
        //echo $exam_board;
    }

?>
```

This is the result of `var_dump($result);`:

`array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "exam_board" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "pearson" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" } array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(9) "exam_code" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "a123" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" } array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "exam_level" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "pearson-a-level" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to `$result->taxonomy` if you see the structure it is a json array so you get it like an object.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please. Do you mean i should replace `$result = $value;` with `$result->taxonomy`?

Comment: No , but you can delete this line and use instead directly `$value->taxonomy;`  after all you are putting the value into result